# What are the differences between old Pottermore and new?

Tags: harry-potter, canon, jk-rowling, pottermore

What parts of the old Pottermore weren't carried over to the new Pottermore?

Conversely, which parts of the new Pottermore weren't on the old Pottermore? (I'm only asking about the parts actually from JK Rowling. Not the stupid Buzzfeed clickbait articles.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Parts of the old Pottermore not carried over:

- The artwork from the quizzes ([Sorting](http://guide-to-pottermore-items.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_29.html) & [Wand](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Ollivanders_Bespoke_Wand_Selector)) (note that the sorting quiz has changed)
- [Dumbledore's Army Reunites at the Quidditch World Cup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlB6H.png) (Some artwork from the other QWC articles are missing)
- Book extracts ([Curses and Counter-Curses](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Curses_and_Counter-Curses#Extract), [The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 1](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/The_Standard_Book_of_Spells,_Grade_1#New_from_J.K._Rowling), [A Beginner's Guide to Transfiguration](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Guide_to_Transfiguration#New_from_J.K._Rowling), [One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/One_Thousand_Magical_Herbs_and_Fungi#New_from_J.K._Rowling), [The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dark_Forces:_A_Guide_to_Self-Protection#New_from_J.K._Rowling), [Book of Spells [video]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKJHQDN4n6Y), [Book of Potions [video]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FpS1KCgK7g))
- Spell (and potion) books ([The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mBAA.jpg), [The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF69C.jpg), [Curses and Counter-Curses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Lx1.jpg), [The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYZsu.jpg), [Magical Drafts and Potions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUQVb.jpg), [Moste Potente Potions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUAxe.jpg), [Book of Potions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCsT9.jpg))
- [Timeline of the Wizarding World](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/2/28/Timeline_of_the_Wizarding_World.png/revision/latest?cb=20150904020044)
- Some of the moment artwork
- some character facts
- The minigames

### Parts of the new Pottermore not on the old:

- Seven new pieces of writing from JK Rowling ([The Potter Family](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-potter-family), [Wizarding Schools](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wizarding-schools) (along with [this map](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/3BU9XeNzJeGMUWqMWqSY02/60e8a6069029a7db1613efae5bcc6dbb/Wizarding_Schools_Map_LR.jpg)), [Castelobruxo](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/castelobruxo), [Mahoutokoro](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/mahoutokoro), [Uagadou](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/uagadou), [History of Magic in North America](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en), [Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny))
- An [Illvermorny Sorting Quiz](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/4qedhl/all_ilvermorny_sorting_quiz_questions/) (probably not written by Rowling)
- A [Patronus test](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/53yufn/pottermore_patronus_test_all_possible_questions/).
- News about *Fantastic Beasts* and *The Cursed Child*
- Stuff about the movies (not always labeled as such)
- Clickbait articles/listicles (e.g. [5-friendship lessons we learned from Dobby the house elf](https://www.pottermore.com/features/5-friendship-lessons-we-learned-from-Dobby-the-house-elf))
- Some infographics ([Wands](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/4hqdYyVVMQsyGYUCaYuiqg/ba61eb8c4b224718eed93e6b2acb0725/Wand_Infographic_Full.jpg), [Magical Objects](http://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/3YzibM5RIkgkqqqmCWaIKq/d6c845aa3a8c869f7fd76c009d850989/PottermoreMagicalObjects.jpg), [Seven](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/4Oizhmxk2IuM0IgCauyKyc/2eabdfc3a1ac7ecc25cf3bbb9b07ca50/SignificanceOfSeven.jpg), [Luna Lovegood](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/7CAxSg43rG2OQ6sesmeaW4/6ae423398825ce2d92fff1aece1f7a00/Luna_Lovegood_Infographic.jpg), [Lavender Brown](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/2sySqAOZuUYgAma2aMAEqG/496ad82d0c6d3a9d91fba0f115a36739/Lavender_Brown_Infographic.jpg), [Ron Weasley](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/5m3cyn5NraYWmaWywc2ayg/2d4cb5b99c4bff4575938efa138e3017/HP_-_Ron_Weasley_Final.jpg), [House Points](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/S0e4WPos6GOw0sk20mGei/d28caa714ae6c5d5fe33206660db3d02/House_Points_Infographic.jpg), [Fred & George](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/5ykgrtG7ssMiwAkCOCMaym/d9b506056d244ef2581f53786efb15f5/Fred_and_George_Weasley_Infographic.jpg), [Fred & George: Troublemakers](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/37FeGqjnK8Aou0gYWeQMw8/8464e58de1cb333c65f27966bd6a153b/Fred_and_George__Troublemakers_in_Chief.jpg), [Battle of Hogwarts](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/6AG4uGgsFyekEUai0GisWm/b50368fd3228a4191d0846f9c3b90441/The_Battle_of_Hogwarts_LR.jpg), [Snape](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/1Zc0x0UHycEE8sCUiSKqoG/be7654a0dfd1a0ca62ab604089ba5913/Severus_Snape_Infographic.jpg), [Draco](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/6Ji0WGmCk02o6Y6cSA0GsC/c47aedc821e57a679db80ad536ff36ca/All_About_Draco_Malfoy.jpg), [Sweets](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/1z0A8QRA7OoEGccmCgQyMm/3ab1074fec517e7e08ac9ff99051164c/Sweets-and-Treats-1.jpg), [Triwizard Tournament](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/4hzSmrv4eAo2YWq2ogOI4U/a94a0791fdf090b7f07a2ad95f37fdf6/PM_Triwizard_Tournament_timeline.jpg), [Neville Longbottom](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/5c6E9QMHba0awCqIEoSmm6/3716d0ab342861ab1809fecb757c88cd/Neville_Longbottom_infographic.jpg), [Minerva McGonagall](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/2J3kCgvY5GM0ou0cSmQou2/412ced9f42b6017398ae4867f247c9c5/Minerva_McGonagall-Infographic.jpg), [Secret Passageways](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/4fPIscDgF2GiC2iGeqIS8W/b3c3499877254d5db1a3e01a4d9adf45/PM_Secret_Passageways_Infographic.jpg))
- Some new artwork (including on the quizzes)
- One new question on the Hogwarts sorting quiz (about pets)
- some character facts

Comment: In addition, in the individual character pages (for, say, McGonagall, Kettleburn, or Ollivander) the fact sheets that contained birth dates, parentage, Hogwarts House, and wand type have for whatever reason been omitted.

Comment: @BolteAltamont Some of that information has been filtering its way back in. [McGonagall's page](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/minerva-mcgonagall), for instance, has all of that stuff again

Comment: The old Pottermore also had "message boards", where users could comment on characters and events, upload drawings or just chat (with many checks and limits due to the young age of many users, for example messages could not contain web links ...); the comment boards and the drawing galleries were removed some time before the end of the old site.

Comment: @JasonBaker https://my.pottermore.com/wand I pressed to try out the quiz, and then clicked away without thinking to test out the format, now I'm annoyed as I can't undo it. (I noticed one new question which wasn't on the old quiz and a completely different format.)

Comment: The Patronus writing will probably get added when the Patronus quiz does.

Comment: @b_jonas - What we're you trying to edit? (I do realize the answer is a bit of of date)

Comment: @ibid I was considering to link https://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/The_Standard_Book_of_Spells,_Grade_2 . This came up when I was searching for answers on this site that mention the old Pottermore as just “Pottermore” and found https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/50095/4918 on memory charms.

Comment: @b_jonas - But isn't that image already linked too?

Comment: @ibid An image of the book, as it appeared in old Pottermore, is linked, but the description page on Pottermore Wikia isn't.

Comment: @b_jonas - the wiki page is just a transcription of the image, the trunk description, and the from the story excerpt. I've avoided those last two categories entirely in this answer.