# Why was the old Pottermore shut down?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling, pottermore

Pottermore used to have an interactive format with lots of original content from J.K. Rowling tightly structured around the Harry Potter books. In September 2015 the site was replaced with something resembling a mixture of Buzzfeed and HP Wiki. [Much of the content wasn't transferred over.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113605/55866)

So why did they switch over? Was the old site costing too much? Did someone up top think that what the fans want is clickbait articles that cannot distinguish between book canon and movie canon?

### Why was the old Pottermore shut down?

Comment: Are you looking for an in-universe or out-of-universe answer? ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In universe is fine as long as it's not from the movies. ;-)

Comment: Is there any known figure concerning the number of workers of the old Pottermore and the new one? I imagine the old site (especially when comments and drawings were allowed) needed an ever growing staff to monitor user-generated content 24/7 (as long as the number of users kept growing), while the new site needs just a small team regardless of the user base size.

Answer (score 54):

According to [an article by *The Bookseller*](http://www.thebookseller.com/news/pottermore-readies-radical-relaunch-312036), Susan Jurevics, Pottermore's CEO, had essentially three reasons. We might argue over whether or not they were good reasons<sup>1</sup>, but these are hers:

1. They don't think gamification is the right approach for their core audience:

   > Jurevics told *The Bookseller*: "When Pottermore first started, it was positioned for the next generation of readers, and that next generation was almost by default tagged to be children. So the current site gamified the content, making it very simplistic in terms of collecting things and casting spells. That was appropriate for children, but that wasn't actually the core audience." Jurevics said that the user base was “overwhelmingly young adult and female"
2. It uses the web more effectively:

   > The relaunch also reflected technological advancements in the way users now access content sites, Jurevics said: "From a technology point of view, when Pottermore was designed and conceived the iPad had not yet been launched, and the population didn't yet sleep with their phones on. The current Pottermore is really a laptop or desktop experience and that type of usage is going away." The new site will be smartphone-first to reflect this "fundamental change in user behaviour", with content designed for touchscreens and swiping.
   >
   > *[...]*
   >
   > For the first time, the site’s content will be made available to search engines and indexed, with additional content derived from numerous sources including filmmaker Warner Bros and other franchisees.

   I didn't have a lot of involvement with the original Pottermore, but from my limited experience it had a number of limitations in this area:

   - **Heavily flash-based.** This is a geek's argument, so I won't delve into it too deeply, but flash is a horrible tool for websites to use, and is especially unfriendly to mobile devices. I have a pretty old laptop, and the old Pottermore made it beg me for death; I shudder to think how it would have gone if my main computing device was an iPad
   - **Content was not shareable**. Not long after the new site went live I went and updated as many of the links to Pottermore content on this site as I could, and I was astonished at the hoops we jumped through to include citation links: Slytherincess probably has about half of the old Pottermore on [her Flickr account](https://www.flickr.com/photos/slytherincess/albums/72157629653674077), and there are/were at least a half-dozen fansites dedicated to archiving the content in a linkable way. The only way to cite things directly from the old Pottermore was to include the name of the Moment, which required someone to sign up for an account and then track that Moment down
   - **Navigation was tedious.** If I remember correctly, Moments you had already unlocked could be reached from a single homepage menu, but finding new content required hunting linearly through the narrative. I recall plenty of furious clicking after I signed up for an account, searching for a particular Moment for information I needed to cite in an answer here
3. It's more flexible about content, allowing material not tied to the narrative:

   > Perhaps the most significant shift is the removal of the central concept behind the original site, which required users to become students of a virtual Hogwarts in order to progress through the books and experience the site. Jurevics said the change reflected the way the Harry Potter series had now evolved outside of the core seven books.
   >
   > She said: "[J K Rowling] finds these corollaries in the real world and evolves the magical world through a lot of the new writing, for example when she created the Quidditch World Cup.
   >
   > But in the very linear narrative—focused on the books—that we had, there was no place for that. She can now write content that is about the wider wizarding world, but is not anchored to books one to seven."

   As we've seen, it also allows them to include other types of content, like news updates, and illustrations

In the same article Anna Rafferty, Pottermore's director of product, creative and content, gave another reason; decoupling Pottermore from the linear narrative structure of the books makes it more accessible to more levels of fan:

> Rafferty said: "We are opening up all that content—this world is expanding and we want people to have access to all of that, whether they are superfans or not. It is no longer a linear experience. It's not a book. You don’t read a website from the home page to chapter one to chapter two, and we needed to reflect that. There are going to be hundreds of thousands of landing pages. It’s an immersive world, but one you can rummage around in."

---

<sup>1</sup> Personally, I think they're excellent reasons. The issues I have with the new Pottermore are almost wholly unrelated to these reasons

Comment: Funny she should mention the QWC, as that was one of the major parts NOT carried over to the new Pottermore.

Comment: If they could only have kept the _information_ of the old Pottermore in the _structure/layout_ of the new one. I absolutely hated the old one for the way it was made (gamified Flash crap—it was a horrible site), but I distrust the new for its content. :-/

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think we all feel that way. (Also, most of the old information can be found online if you look hard enough. Even the QWC stuff)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet And I put *gamified Flash crap* over Buzzfeed listicles.

Comment: I didn’t realise Pottermore had been going for that long.

Comment: I don't know that I have screenshots of *half* the original site, but if anyone wants to look at them, they are located [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/slytherincess/albums/72157629653674077) on Flickr. Related meta question: [What is the best way to deal with complicated canon discrepancies when answering](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-complicated-canon-discrepancies-when-answering). I used Pottermore as my example in this question.

Comment: @Slytherincess I have links to a lot more of it [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113609/55866) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114611/55866)

Comment: @ibid maybe you should request an https://archive.is (an archiving website) copy of that old information when you happen to pass by a bit...

Comment: so she says "didn't rock as business and was tedious for Rowling". wonder how much truth is exposed in that, though, with all that folk talk about missing content...

Comment: @n611x007 - The old Pottermore was heavily flash-based, and all behind a login screen.

Comment: @ibid I remember... I was under the imporession that the you pass by the old information *elsewhere*. Now I can't recognize it (as I didn't like logging in; would have preferred a book), but you might, I mean, most likely would.

Comment: @n611x007 - But what's the point in an archive of an archive? I think I've provided links to everything in the two posts I've linked to above. Feel free to archive.is them all. (Though I assume they're all already in the Wayback Machine.)

Comment: @ibid wayback scrawls in itself and they decided it should honor robots.txt retroactively. archive.is archives a single site on personal request and do not filter retroactively. the first layer of your posts is done now.

Comment: @n611x007 - I also maintain offline and physical copies. Just in case.

Comment: correction: `single site` was meant to be "single ***page***". Somehow wrote the wrong word. Great to hear about the physicals, may they serve you very well.