# Where can I find Harry Potter game called "Pottermore"?

Tags: harry-potter, games, pottermore

What is the Pottermore game and where can I play this?

Comment: I thought "Pottermore" was the old name for JKR's website now called "[Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/)."  If you're sure there's a game by this name, where did you hear about it and what do you know about it?

Comment: never heard about a game called "Pottermore"... as stated by David this was the name of the original website of JKR....

Comment: maybe the Patronus picker and House Sorting would be the closest thing I could think of on Pottermore that could be considered games

Comment: The first _Pottermore_ had some more gaming elements that were not present in its subsequent versions (finding hidden objects in the images, making potions, duelling). I'm quite sure there is a question asking for the differences between the old and new _Pottermore_.

Comment: Here is the question I was referring to: [_What are the differences between old Pottermore and new?_](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113605/40711)

Answer (score 4):

*[Pottermore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pottermore)* was the precursor to what is now *[Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com)*. It was, like its successor, an online resource for all things related to *Harry Potter*.

It was launched in early 2012 and was replaced by *Wizarding World* in 2019. Most of the content was migrated there.

J.K. Rowling occasionally posted original materials, supplemental to the books and films.